# Finding Lipschitz Constant for Matrix Square Root Function

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, lipschitz-functions

I am working on a problem where I need to know the Lipschitz constant for the matrix square root function. The function is given by $f(A)=\sqrt{A}$

$ \Vert f(X) -f(Y) \Vert \leq L\Vert X-Y \Vert$

Where X and Y are positive definite matrices.
How can I determine or estimate the Lipschitz constant L
for the matrix square root function in this setting? Are there known bounds or perturbation results in matrix analysis that can provide this constant?
(when the eigenvalue is bounded away from zero and two positive definites there may exist a local Lipschitz constant?)

Comment: Do you think the square root function is Lipschitz? How about 1x1 matrices, so the square root function $f:R\to R$?

Comment: Just like the scalar square root, there's no Lipschitz constant. Consider $X = \sqrt{a}I$ and $Y = 0$. Then, $\|f(X)-f(Y)\| = \|\sqrt{a}I-0\| = \sqrt{a}$ and $\|X-Y\| = \|aI-0\| = a$, so you'd need $\sqrt{a} \le La$ for all $a$, which for any $L$ fails for $0 < a < \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{L}}$.

Comment: Welcome to the Math Stack Exchange. What have you tried so far?

Comment: i think when the eigenvalue is bounded away from zero and two positive definites there may exist a local Lipschitz constant? sorry i am super new to this topic